# Product prize(regular) is showing zero for all products

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I'm facing a serious problem. In my website all product prizes are showing zero. I didn't set any special prize or grouped prize in product settings. This is my image which shows like this in 90% of products.Currently I'm using Magento 1.9 version.

[image]

Comment: check wether your simple/grouped products are in stock, if not, it may show 0

Comment: What is the price shown in the cart?

Comment: @JulienLachal : all are in stock

Comment: @Thorsten: in product listing it shows the actual prize but in product details page and cart page it shows zero

Comment: OK, if the price in the cart is wrong it cannot be an index or cache issue. The cart price is always calculated directly. Do you have any catalog or cart price rules? What is the price shown in the backend?

Comment: One Catalog rule was there. I deleted this one. Now the customer says it working.But not working on the products which is already uploaded.

Answer (score 3):

According to your screenshot shown i found that your regular price is 5000 and the price is shown is special price , please make sure that what you enter for all product prince as special price.

> please do blank the special price block so that your regular price
>   show as 5000 as you shown in screenshot.

hope this will helps you.

Comment: I kept blank in special price...in product listing it shows the actual prize but in product details page and cart page it shows zero

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem, after checking database i found some weird entries in catalogrule_product_price, deleting them all helped me to solve this.

Don't forget to make a backup of this table before u delete any entries from it.